# How can I encrypt a string in Apex in a way that an external system can decrypt using C#?

Tags: apex, security, c#, encryption, decrypt

Our security team has found an issue in our lightning experience site where a link to an external system is adding the account # in the URL. That system is then using that account # to display data on their site related to the account.

This means any user who can access this link can modify the account # in the URL and see other people's data in the external system (big oops to whomever designed that).

I was thinking the easiest way to fix this is to encrypt the account # so the external system can still grab the encrypted # from the URL, decrypt it, and show the correct information.

Below is the code I created to encrypt this account # in Apex (This is just a sample key):

```
private static final Blob KEY = EncodingUtil.base64Decode('ZZZB0LSDWRlPSpOR3LgqSpZdN0DCJYcxohJ/K3oPsA=');

private static String encryptString(String clearText) {
    Blob encryptedBlob = Crypto.encryptWithManagedIV('AES256', KEY, Blob.valueOf(clearText));
    String encryptedText = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(encryptedBlob);
    return encryptedText;
}
```

I told the external systems developer to use the key provided above as well as `AES256` to decrypt the value and he says this isn't enough info.

How can I encrypt a value in a way where another system can decrypt it? Is it as simple as giving him the key and the encryption method (`AES256`)?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

David is absolutely right and I'd like to add some extra information and provide code examples regarding `Apex-encryption`/`C#-decryption`.

To encrypt some `String` in `Apex` using the `AES256-CBC` algorithm you can:

1. Generate private key:

```
final Blob privateKey = Crypto.generateAesKey(256);
```

2. Store somewhere the generated key as Base64 `String`:

```
// System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, EncodingUtil.base64Encode(privateKey)); 
// e.g. 'lX8rtkgjlgQ5fyWH+G8XUPLlc04zZ8lTtrxpJSlmdhs='
```

3. Create the `encrypt` method in the `Encryptor` class:

```
public static String encrypt(final String clearText, final String key) {
    final Blob encrypted = Crypto.encryptWithManagedIV(
        'AES256',
        EncodingUtil.base64Decode(key),
        Blob.valueOf(clearText)
    );
    return EncodingUtil.base64Encode(encrypted);
}
```

The catch here is that [Crypto.encryptWithManagedIV()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_classes_restful_crypto.htm) method

> stores the **initialization vector** as the **first 128 bits (16 bytes)** of the encrypted `Blob`.

This information is crucial and we will use it for decryption later.

4. Then you can encrypt some string text and send it to an external system as Base64 string:

```
Encryptor.encrypt('Hello World', 'lX8rtkgjlgQ5fyWH+G8XUPLlc04zZ8lTtrxpJSlmdhs='); 
// 'QEwvBfLu5luAdlWb0Yk96eu4X0egOIYtHl0nJn+UJlc='
```

5. To decrypt a string using `AES256-CBC` algorithm in `C#` write the next method using [Aes Class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aes?view=netcore-3.1) ([AesManaged](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged?view=netcore-3.1), [RijndaelManaged](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged?view=net-7.0) and [Rijndael](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged?view=net-7.0) classes are **obsolete**):

```
static string Decrypt(string iVAndCipherText, string keyStr) {
    byte[] encryptedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(iVAndCipherText);
    byte[] cipherTextBuffer = new byte[encryptedBytes.Length - 16];
    // Copies a payload skipping first 16 bytes into cipherTextBuffer var
    Array.Copy(encryptedBytes, 16, cipherTextBuffer, 0, cipherTextBuffer.Length); 
    byte[] iv = new byte[16];
    // Copies the first 16 bytes of a payload as IV into iv var
    Array.Copy(encryptedBytes, iv, 16);
    Aes aes = Aes.Create("AesManaged")!;
    // aes.BlockSize = 128; by default
    // aes.KeySize = 256; by default
    // aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC; by default
    // aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7; by default
    aes.Key = Convert.FromBase64String(keyStr);
    aes.IV = iv;
    ICryptoTransform decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor();
    byte[] decryptedData = decryptor.TransformFinalBlock(cipherTextBuffer, 0, cipherTextBuffer.Length);
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptedData);
}
```

Once again, the catch here was to take **first 16 bytes as IV** and the **rest bytes as the payload to be decrypted**.

Result:

```
string iVAndCipherText = "QEwvBfLu5luAdlWb0Yk96eu4X0egOIYtHl0nJn+UJlc="; // Payload gotten from Apex (p.4)
string key = "lX8rtkgjlgQ5fyWH+G8XUPLlc04zZ8lTtrxpJSlmdhs="; // AES256 generated key (p.2)
string decrypted = Decrypt(iVAndCipherText, key);
Console.WriteLine(decrypted); // "Hello World"
```

Answer (score 4):

The data I would think an external systems developer would need are:

- The algorithm: AES256.
- The cipher mode: Cipher Block Chaining (CBC), as documented for the [Apex `Crypto` class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_classes_restful_crypto.htm).
- The padding mode: PKCS7 (same link).
- The fact that you are using a managed initialization vector.
- The fact they you're transmitting the data in Base64.
- And of course, the key.

Apex cryptography provides a much more limited set of options than most cryptography libraries in other languages, so you'll probably need to share these built-in assumptions with your colleague.